# QGIS Join Attributes by Location not working from Python script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a shapefile with points, and a shapefile with polygons. I want to sum the attribute value of all points that are within a certain polygon, and I'd like to do this for each polygon in my dataset. QGIS Join Attributes by Location tool is helping me to achieve this, and is working perfectly when using the tool via the Processing Toolbox. However, I would like to include the tool in an automated script. I tried many different arguments, but my code is (still) not working, and results in a dataset where the new polygon attribute has NULL values.

I'm using the following code, which should be exactly the same as the tool is running when I'm accessing it from the Processing Toolbox (I even tried copying and running the exact same code from the History & Log window):

```
sum = processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation","polygonlayer.shp",
                        "pointlayer.shp","['contains']",1,"sum",1,None)
```

I'm using QGIS 2.8.2 Wien.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE Linda! Are you sure the algorithm is not `qgis:joinbylocation` which is what I have?

Comment: Thanks! Using qgis:joinbylocation does not work for me ("Error: Algorithm not found"). Are you using QGIS 2.8.2?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I didn't update the _processing_ plugin. I always forget this!

Comment: [Similar problem here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147450/why-does-join-attributes-by-location-fail-to-compute-sums-when-used-in-a-model) too as it also doesn't work through the modeler.

Comment: Most welcome, as mentioned in a comment by @mike from the post I linked, downgrading the _processing_ plugin to 2.2 and using the `qgis:joinbylocation` tool works. I just downgraded it again as I personally consider it very stable even though it has less tools available than the latest versions. You can download the plugin from [here](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing/) and unzip the folder to your _C:\Users\You\.qgis2\python\plugins_ directory. Hope this helps a little anyway!

Comment: Thanks! Missed the link in your previous comment at first. I'll give the downgrade a try! Hope it won't affect too many other tools in my script ;)

Answer (score 2):

- For QGIS 2.8.2 with *Processing* plugin 2.9.0:

  ```
  processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", layer1, layer2, u'contains', 1, 'sum', 1, None)
  ```
- For QGIS 2.12.2 with *Processing* plugin 2.12.2:

  ```
  processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", layer1, layer2, u'contains', 0, 1, 'sum', 1, None)
  ```

  (*note the extra parameter for "precision"*)