# QGIS:joinattributesbylocation gives empty shapefiles and QGIS:joinbylocation does not give summary of all fields

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatial-join

I am trying to make a spatial join to calculate the mean value of many variables (100+ columns) of census tracts by city. In order to do that, I would, in QGIS Desktop, run a spatial join (join attributes by location). I did it and it worked. However, I need to automate the process and use the command line "processing" commands ("processing.runalg...").

Even tough it works in QGIS and should work in command line with the following line: 
processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", neighborsPath, censusPath, "['intersects']",1,"mean", 0, layerOutput)
The process works, but gives an empty shapefile (1kb size).

As suggested in many posts ([Why does "Join attributes by location" fail to compute sums when used in a model?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147450/why-does-join-attributes-by-location-fail-to-compute-sums-when-used-in-a-model)) and ([QGIS Join Attributes by Location not working from Python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150267/qgis-join-attributes-by-location-not-working-from-python-script)), I downgraded processing to v.2.2.0, and used the *joinbylocation*, the result only gives me stats for the first column of my joined shapefile and not for the 100+ columns I have. 
This is the line that I am using:
processing.runalg("qgis:joinbylocation", neighborsPath, censusPath, 1, 'mean', 0,1, layerOutput)

I don't know if one of you encountered this problem and successfully fixed it.
(p.s. I tried all versions of Processing)
I hope someone can help me! (This is my first question on stackexchange, I hope it's well formulated enough)

Also, qgis:extractbylocation also gives empty shapefiles, for an unknown reason... So the cause might be the same in both cases.

The files are all in WGS84 CRS

Here is the code I am using:

```
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from os import walk
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')
ogr2ogr = r"C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\ogr2ogr.exe"
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
Processing.updateAlgsList()

neighborsPath = r"C:\Users\JoeNavut\Desktop\tests\wgs84\corrected_geom\calgary.shp" #PATH TO NEIGHBOR FILE
censusPath =  r"C:\Users\JoeNavut\Desktop\tests\wgs84\corrected_geom\censusData.shp" #PATH TO CENSUS FILE

layerOutput = neighborsPath.replace(".shp", "_Criteria.shp")
layerInput = QgsVectorLayer(neighborsPath, "file_to_calculate", "ogr")
censusInput = QgsVectorLayer(censusPath, "file_for_calc", "ogr")
print layerInput.isValid()
print censusInput.isValid()
try:
    processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", neighborsPath, censusPath, "['intersects']",1,"mean", 0, layerOutput)
    print "Criteria calculations complete"
except:
   print "Criteria calculations failed"
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.exit()
```

[image]

And in QGIS, we see that the table has been created, but is empty...
[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! This text currently reads like two questions. Please note that the format of this Q&A site demands that each thread focuses on only one question. Therefore, please separate the two issues so they can be answered separately. (ad the extractbylocation issue: include information about the input CRS. screenshots would help too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your `"['intersects']"` from your *processing.runalg* line to `u'intersects'` instead:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", neighborsPath, censusPath, u'intersects', 1, "mean", 0, layerOutput)
```

I had this problem before, tested this and works with QGIS 2.10.1-Pisa; *Processing* version 2.10.2.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @JonathanGaudreau - Awesome buddy! Glad you got it working :)