# Join Attributes By Location inside QGIS modeler still fails to compute sums

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, qgis-modeler, qgis-2.12

Recently, a [question was asked about the spatial join tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147450/why-does-join-attributes-by-location-fail-to-compute-sums-when-used-in-a-model), and its failure to calculate the desired data.

I ran into the same problem, but none of the solutions that were offered there solved it.

1. I ran the tool as a standalone process, and it worked fine
2. I made sure both my layers (a polygon and a point) are the same CRS, still failed
3. downgrading is not an option

Running 64bit standalone 2.12.1 Lyon on Windows 7

Comment: Which Processing version are you running?

Comment: version 2.12.2.